# ¿Cómo creo un perfil dns en mac os x?

Tags: ubuntu, redirección, dns

Tengo montado un servidor local en ubuntu con una pagina y con una ip privada fija, el cual replica una base de datos hacia internet y hace las tareas en la red local.

¿Es posible configurar en mac, que al momento de ingresar a subdominio.dominio.com redireccione a la ip de mi servidor montado?

Gracias

Comment: Hola podrías describir un poco más tu problema, creo que así como está no se entiende bien. saludos

Comment: Hola héctor, actualmente tengo la misma página en internet y en la red local, pero quiero que accedan a la máquina virtual ingresando la url en lugar de la ip ¿será posible? Saludos